# $_SESSION vars being set to null on GoDaddy

Tags: php, mysqli, session-variables, godaddy-api

This is a basic login script i created an on XAMMP server on my local computer. Worked perfectly fine on the local server. Uploaded it to my windows deluxe go daddy hosting service and it no longer works. The script is properly pulling in the user name and password the user is entering and is correctly validating it. However it seems that the $_SESSION vars are being set to null. However i know that the array it is using to set the vars is not null because it is in fact using same array to validate the login credentials. Currently when you login you get the success message in the url bar as set in the code and correctly get errors when you should, so validation is not the issue. Also i have double checked that the session is indeed been started, however it appears to not be updating. I also have the session_start() method in my header which is included in all my pages as an independent script that in included at the top of the page. i have tried removing it and having the login script be the only code that starts that session and it doesn't make a difference. However, if i include the setting of the session vars in the header itself it works fine. So somehow the session vars are being set to null. Any ideas?
Edit2: you can go to selfscales.com to see the bug in action

```
<?php

 session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
include 'dbh.inc.php';
$uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

//error handlers 
//check if inputs are empty
if(empty($uid) || empty($pwd)){
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=empty");
    exit();

} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid='$uid' OR user_email='$uid'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($resultCheck < 1) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
        exit();
    } else {
        if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            //deashing the password 
            $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_pwd']);
            if($hashedPwdCheck == false){
            header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
            exit();
            } elseif ($hashedPwdCheck == true) {
                //login in the user here
                $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                $_SESSION['u_first'] = $row['user_first'];
                $_SESSION['u_last'] = $row['user_last'];
                $_SESSION['u_email'] = $row['user_email'];
                $_SESSION['u_uid'] = $row['user_uid'];
                header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
                exit();
            }
            }
    }
}


     }
  else {
   header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
   exit();
    }
```

Edit1: Index Page

```
<?php
  include_once 'header.php';
   include 'includes/ssdb.inc.php';
  ?>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="testingPHP/stylesheets/w3.css">
    <section class="main-container">
    <div class="main-wrapper">
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['u_id'])){
        echo '<h2>Weigh</h2>';
     } else{
        echo '<h2>Welcome To Selfscale!</h2>';
        echo '<h4>Selfscale is a web application that eliminates the need 
        for a scalehouse.</h4>';
        echo '<h4>Selfscale allows truck drivers to purchase a weigh 
          without the need to talk to anyone.</h4>';
        echo '<h4>Please sign in or login.</h4>';
        echo '<h4> Notice: First time users will need to register their 
        company, truck and trailer.</h4>';
        echo '<h4>Then purchase a weigh for a small fee.</h4>';
        echo '<h4>You will have the option to download your weigh ticket, 
         email it to yourself, or print it out the old fashion way.</h4>';
        include 'weighForm.php';
     }



    ?>
    <?php
     if(isset($_SESSION['u_id'])){

     }
     ?>

</div>
</section>

 <?php
 include_once 'footer.php';
 ?>
```

Comment: How are you determining that the session vars are null? The example doesn't show them being used, only set. Can you also show us the code that uses the session vars and finds them null?

Comment: Okay i added the index page that looks for the session var u_id to check to see if someone is loged in and that var is being set to null

Comment: well that looks okay. Perhaps the session is getting lost betwen pages. In your header.php after the session_start() try adding `echo(session_name());` and see if the session name stays the same as you move between pages.

Comment: Okay did that. i get "PHPSESSID". looking in the memory of the web browser while im in the site the value doesnt appear to change nor does the name. is there a way to manually change the name of the cookie in the code to see if it updates?

Comment: In my login.php file i named the session and it then creates a separate cookie in the browser session_name('test'); and i now have to cookies. test and phpsessid. is there a way to reference a cookie by name in the code?

Comment: sorry, I should have said session_id not name, but you've just confirmed that the id value in the cookie is staying the same, so it looks like the session is sticking between pages. Perhaps try sticking a var_dump($_SESSION) at the start of your index page, just after the includes and you can see what the session vars look like at each stage.

Comment: I get array(0) { }. so the array is indeed null. why would this be?

Comment: Im not getting run time errors or anything, so somehow the array is being cleared or updated somehow. which i dont understand because this worked just fine on my local machine

Comment: If i set a session var in the header the var will stay between pages, however it appears to be deleting the array when the page is redirected after login

Comment: That's is really weird. exit() should write out the session. You could try popping a session_write_close() between the header('location'....) and exit().

Comment: Still no luck...

Answer (score 1):

In the end I called GoDaddy support. The issue was the default save path for the session_start() method was not an actual dir in the server. This was an issue on their end and was resolved quickly. Thanks to anyone that attempted to help!

Comment: I am certain that is what happened with one of my sites. But I cannot get their tech to realize it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `ob_start()` on top of your script that may solve your problem.

```
<?php
 ob_start();
 session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
include 'dbh.inc.php';
$uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

//error handlers 
//check if inputs are empty
if(empty($uid) || empty($pwd)){
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=empty");
    exit();

} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid='$uid' OR user_email='$uid'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($resultCheck < 1) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
        exit();
    } else {
        if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            //deashing the password 
            $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_pwd']);
            if($hashedPwdCheck == false){
            header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
            exit();
            } elseif ($hashedPwdCheck == true) {
                //login in the user here
                $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                $_SESSION['u_first'] = $row['user_first'];
                $_SESSION['u_last'] = $row['user_last'];
                $_SESSION['u_email'] = $row['user_email'];
                $_SESSION['u_uid'] = $row['user_uid'];
                header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
                exit();
            }
            }
    }
}


     }
  else {
   header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
   exit();
    }
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.
For more understanding of `ob_start()`

Refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and i understand how that in supposed to work, however it is not...